# Which is quicker at fetching a result given an search in python. A list of dicts or a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, performance, dictionary

I import, *from a json file*, the following object:

```
"loan_numbers":[
    {"symbol":1000114, "val":0.1},
    {"symbol":1000150, "val":0.15},
    {"symbol":1000074, "val":0.11}
]
```

The above is a list of dicts.

My question is this. If i wanted to search for "symbol" (eg.1000150) and return "val" (eg. 0.15) which method would be quicker:

- [method 1] iterating through the list of dicts (for i in loan_numbers, if i['symbol']==1000150, v= val)

or

- [method 2] populate a pandas data frame and search (df.loc[df['symbol'] == 1000150, 'val'])

I was going to test both side-by-side, but was wondering if there is an accepted **pythonic** method or if one method was considerably faster than another under certain conditions (for example, i have a feeling that for longer lists the DataFrame would be faster because of its types).

I have done some searches, on stack overflow and also google, which show both as viable, but not which "is preferred" or why.

Comment: It is difficult to answer such a question. The best way to go is to implement both and check the timing.

Comment: agree with comment above, I guess dict should be faster. But if need some another operations then it is really complicated working with list of dicts, then better is use pandas.

Comment: If you have a small amount of data then you should use lists if is not the case instead use pandas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering both of your approaches I ran a simulation on both functions for list sizes up to 2^26 (~67 million records).
At every search, a `symbol` is randomly chosen from the list using `random.choice()`, then we search back this `symbol` to return the associated `val`. Be careful, based on my understanding you would create the `pandas.DataFrame` specifically to search through it, this is why I included the creation of the `pandas.DataFrame` in the function, in other words it is also timed.

The following results are as follows:
[image: perfplot results]

Based on this quick analysis, you would need to have a list with more than 100 million records to start using `pandas` over a simple loop.

The code used is:

```py
import random

import perfplot
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def standard_iteration(loan_dict):
     random_symbol = random.choice(loan_dict['loan_numbers'])['symbol']
     for loan in loan_dict['loan_numbers']:
          if loan['symbol'] == random_symbol:
               return loan['val']

def dataframe_filtering(loan_dict):
    random_symbol = random.choice(loan_dict['loan_numbers'])['symbol']
    df = pd.DataFrame(loan_dict['loan_numbers'])
    return df[df['symbol'] == random_symbol]['val'].iloc[0]

perfplot.show(
    setup=lambda n: {'loan_numbers': [{'symbol': i, 'val': j} for i, j in enumerate(np.random.rand(n))]},  # or setup=np.random.rand
    kernels=[
        standard_iteration,
        dataframe_filtering,
    ],
    labels=["Standard iteration", "Dataframe filtering"],
    n_range=[2 ** k for k in range(26)],
    xlabel="len(a)",
    equality_check=None
)
```

Comment: This is a very complete answer for which I was not expecting the result that standard iterations are quicker (given that pandas uses numpy datatypes). But then notice that you have validly considered the creation of the pandas dataframe and how it might be used.

Comment: I just ran the same for a small size list and this came out as 0.011 seconds (for iterating a list) compared to 0.055 seconds (for implementing a dataframe.   A list is therefore approximately 5 times faster (for small lists at least).